# RAD Studio: How do I build my C++ application so it is ready to be distributed?

Tags: c++builder, rad-studio

I have used RAD Studio's C++Builder to make a really simple Windows 32-bit app. I went to `Project > Deployment` and selected all libraries/dependencies I needed and clicked Build.

When I sent the folder with all the app files to someone else, they couldn't run the app because of a missing dependency (which I have on my PC in another place, which is why the app runs on my machine).

[image: Error Message]

That dependency was checked in the deployment menu.

How do I build my application so it can be run on other PCs?

I have tried making both a Debug and a Release build. Also selected all possible Windows 32-bit dependencies and libraries in the deployment menu.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Deploy the missing files to each PC
2. Turn off the following settings to remove the external dependancies in the first place, so the compiled `.exe` is self-contained:

   - [Project > Options > Packages > Runtime Packages](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Runtime_Packages_(Options))

     - Link with runtime packages
   - [Project > Options > Building > C++ Linker](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Linker)

     - Link with Dynamic RTL